# Replicating a bug on client's machine

Tags: c, debugging

I'm currently studying C at university. I've been tasked to write a C program which gives the correct output on my PC and the University's PC's but not on the professor's PC. The professor has provided me with the output of my program on his PC and he has tasked me to find the bug.

I looked at the logic and the expected output and there is no correlation between them. Surely it is not a logic error if it is running on 2 out of 3 computer.

When I asked the professor to mark the assignment based on the school's computer, he disagree and ranted on about the real world that if it doesn't work on just one computer, my program is buggy.

So I want to ask real world professionals out there what they would do in this situation? How can you debug a program if the program is not buggy on the tool provided to you for testing purposes? That is, if a customer report a bug which you cannot replicate yourself, what can you do? Or how do you go about replicating the bug?

FYI, my computer is windows, the school's computer is linux, and the professor's computer is a Mac.

Comment: "Surely it is not a logic error if it is running on 2 out of 3 computer." - don't be so sure.

Comment: If you would provide specific information about the program code or its output it would help us to help you.

Comment: @Havenard I think it's more interesting as a general question.

Comment: the easiest way is to try on the client's machine. it's reasonable to state that as long as you don't have access to a similar machine it's impossible to investigate the problem properly. this is what people mean by saying "we don't support linux"

Comment: @Havenard my program has 750 lines of codes. And there are 8 expected output files. If you have the time I can PM you my code and expected output to run and test? FYI, the program solves a sudoku puzzle in stages and outputs the files into a PDFLATEX code.

Comment: Use http://pastebin.com

Comment: @Alex I agree. I told the professor that it is impossible if I don't have the necessary tool to debug with and he just ranted on about blaming my own code and not his machine... he is very defensive about it. Do you think I should ask to "borrow" his laptop?

Comment: @chrolli: I think borrowing is too much to ask. I guess if you get the possibility to debug on his machine or get the tools he used running on your pc it would help. try to find out whether he uses 64bit/32bit powerpc or intel. perhaps having the same compiler will be sufficient already.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were a few unititialized variables causing the undefined behaviour. Had a load of fun with them during my C programming course.

Comment: If you haven't done this already turn on compiler warnings as high as you can. This will output potential errors that you might not find by your self. Also try and compile with different types of compilers. Some compilers will output different warnings.

Comment: Surely at a university you can find a Mac, post an ad on a bulletin board asking to use one for an hour if you have no friends with one or labs.  If the professor programs  it's likely he knows what is wrong with your program.  Most Mac-uniqueness would give you errors or truncated output, not output that is different in no suggestive way.

Comment: Since you mentioned a Mac, is that machine by any chance an old PowerPC based Mac? If so, then your issue might very well be the fact that those CPUs run in big-endian mode. Commonly such issue bites you whenever you are importing binary data (file, network, ...) while assuming a certain endianness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I looked at the logic and the expected output and there is no correlation between them. Surely it is not a logic error if it is running on 2 out of 3 computer.

Welcome to Undefined Behavior: unfortunately, the fact that your program produces correct results on two (or on two thousand, for that matter) computers proves nothing. The language standard tried to give compiler designers as much freedom to optimize as possible, so that the efficiency of C++ programs could stay competitive with programs written in assembly language. Unfortunately, this leaves a lot of room for incompatibility between platforms: different compilers and execution environments can generate drastically different results for programs with bugs. The worst thing is, programs with bugs may produce behavior that you may reasonably expect on some platforms, and crash miserably on others!

The only way to guard against undefined behavior is to write correct programs. Compilers reasonably aid you by producing warnings in places where they think an undefined behavior may be happening. Turn on all warnings at the finest level, compile your program, and fix all warnings the compiler reports. Chances are, some of the warnings would explain the differences between the output on your computer and on the computer of your professor.

For tracking down advanced errors, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). This program will help you detect memory-related issues, such as writing past the allocated area, using released memory, freeing the same chunk of memory multiple times, and so on.

Comment: Additionally, writting a log file that documents the steps your program perform and inner values (= state) can help.

Comment: Turning on optimizations may help. As compilers might remove code like wrong NULL checking.

Comment: @SJuan76 The log idea sounds great. I will write my program to log the program states and variable values along the way and ask the professor to send me the log file.

Comment: I will mark this answer as the correct answer as I believe that logging will help me debug programs on a machine that I do not have access to.

Answer (score 2):

1) Defensive programming. Do not assume that things will work. Do you need to open a file? Check that it exists. Do you load a data structure? Check the data structure was correct.

1a) Meaningful user errors: If the file is not there, show the user a "Could not find file 'file.txt' in path C:\items". Do not just keep going ahead.

2) As posted in a comment, log everything. More for a school project (where performance is not critical), log everything into a file and check what is the path your program is doing, and (when possible), why (what are the data structure values).

2a) Given the close relationship, you can define a test case for the professor to run in its computer. Check his log against yours.

Answer (score 1):

I am ceratinly not a "real world professional", but I'll try (and will get commented, I'm sure):

First, I would look through the code, and try to see whether are there any "undefined behaviors" creeping there. see @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Second, I will look for OS-dependent code. path seperators, hard-coded `sizeof`s, little-big endian problems, etc.

Third, I would try to find a similar machine. It could be the original one, of course, but since it's not available you can look for virtual-machine images, or check if amazon can give you something like that (they do, but I don't know what OSs are available; I assume OS X is not).

Forth, I would try to build a version loaded with debug helpers and logging, and hand it to to the client, if he is willing to be give a hand.